# How to parallelize the code (symmetric matrix) with OpenMP?

Tags: openmp

I have a very easy code like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
  for(int j=i; j<size; ++j)
      Function(a[i][j])
```

Assume Function() is very time-consuming, so I would like to parallelize the code with OpenMP. If j starts from 0 as well, it will be easy. However, j starts from i, like a symmetric matrix. The problem is that how to parallelize the code in this style? I think there must be someone has this experience and thanks in advance.

Comment: without knowing what function does to a, it is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A naive parallelisation, wrapping the outer loop in a parallel for directive should work. Insert the line

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

before your first `for` statement.  I write Fortran not C so I won't guarantee the syntax is correct, but you should get the idea.  OpenMP will distribute the iterations across `i` according to the schedule you set, or the default schedule if you don't set one explicitly.

The problem with this is that the loops over `j` have very different trip counts, the first (when `i==0`) has `size` iterations, the last (when `i==size-1`) has 0.  So a naive implementation with a static schedule will lead to a grossly imbalanced program.  Use a dynamic schedule, like this

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, CHUNKSIZE)
```

`CHUNKSIZE` is an integer, figure out what might be an appropriate value.

I have assumed that your function call is free of side effects and iteration dependencies that wreck the approach I've outlined.